# How can I find out which resistor is short-circuited and can be ignored?

Tags: resistance, short-circuit

I don't understand how the current flows in the circuit below. How do I deal with the wire between nodes c and a, a and b, g and d. Why is the 5 Ω resistor shorted out? I am having a little trouble understanding what results from short circuiting.

[image]

Comment: "Why"? Because whoever gave you that homework thought it would be an interesting case to learn from.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Yes, as @PlasmaHH wrote - the edge cases are great places to learn from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you're mistaken about "nodes a, b and c" and how you deal with the wires between them. They are actually all the **same** node because they are connected by a wire, and so they also have the same voltage.

This is how you should name your nodes:

[image: Nodes]

Answer (score 1):

Your convention is wrong. If you don't see any resistors across a line then you don't need to change the node name.

Here's the corrected circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fE13gq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As you can see, both ends of the 5-Ohm resistor has "a", so it's shorted out.

Answer (score 0):

There is no empty wires, just wires.

The convention in circuit drawing is that nodes connected by wires are at the same voltage, which means that the voltage at node a (Va) is the same as the voltage at node b (Vb) and c (Vc).

In turn, we know that the voltage across your 5 ohm resistor (Vc-Vb) = 0V, which means that it is in fact shorted out.